# Angularjs get the last or currently change model name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There can be different kind of input elements on the page. Assume, each element is bound to a model. Is there a way to get the currently changing or,last recent modified model name when any of input element's value is changed ? ( 'watch' can be used, but then it will be required to add each element to watch. I think of a way without watch assigned to each element: "A common listerner")

Comment: You can then in case use $broadcast or $emit and catch it with scope.on with every input element for your task .

Comment: @squiroid. Thank you for your reply. Then, all elements are required to be broadcast or emit.. one by one.. .Isn't it? What I feel better is, having a common listener and output the model name or any useful info..

Comment: use ng-change to emit or broadcast the event :-)

Comment: Would you be opposed to creating an attribute directive you could add to inputs that you want to track, and have it handle the broadcast?

Answer (score 2):

If you have all your models under the same object, you can perform a deep watch on that object and build an history.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.email" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.details.phone" />
```

And a controller

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        details: {}
    };

    var lastValue;

    // Deep watch ('true' as last argument)
    $scope.$watch('user', function (newVal, oldVal) {
       // Add to history (create a copy)
       lastValue = angular.copy(oldVal);
    }, true);
}
```

**If you are using Angular 1.3+**

You can look at ngModelOptions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions if you want better control over when a model is updated.

Additionally you can look at $rollbackViewValue() on the FormController and ngModelController: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$rollbackViewValue, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$rollbackViewValue

Comment: Thanks. My elements are actually included in one object. Some attributes have arrays, numbers, strings. However, can you let me know how to get the model name ?? (For instance, from your example, how to check whether changed value is user.name or user.email ??)

Comment: If you want to do something on a per model basis then you won't be able to use a global watch, or you need more computation to determine what has changed between newVal and oldVal: something like https://github.com/flitbit/diff. But it starts to add more complexity...